# ALTER COLUMN NOT NULL in a stored procedure always executes non-sequentially?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

Every week my client sends me a database with a very large table in it with no primary key, and the column with a unique ID in it is nullable.

So I run `ALTER TABLE` to set the column I want as the primary key to NOT NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders 
    ALTER COLUMN OrderID varchar(10) NOT NULL;
```

Then after about 45 minutes that completes and I add my primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_OrdersOrderID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderID)
```

All fine and great so far.

Until that is, I try and automate this long and tedious operation.

I created a very simple stored procedure, which runs as soon as my client's database is finished restoring, as part of an Agent Job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddPKey
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders ALTER COLUMN OrderID varchar(10) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders ADD CONSTRAINT PK_OrdersOrderID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderID)
END
GO
```

This fails after 1 second, with the error message:

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'Orders'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8111)  Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1750). The step failed.

So it's trying to set the primary key constraint before the prior `ALTER COLUMN` step has finished. It should be at least 45 minutes before it attempts to add the primary key constraint, but it tries to do it straight away. If I run the `ALTER COLUMN` manually, it works just fine.

What gives? I've written dozens of stored procedures and none of them behave like that?

What can I do to force it to wait? I thought that's what the semicolon at the end of the `ALTER COLUMN` line did?

UPDATE:

Many thanks to π for the insightful answer and clarification over what's actually happening here. My final stored proc looks like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
 ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders ALTER COLUMN OrderID varchar(10) NOT NULL;
SET @DynamicSQL = 'ALTER TABLE Live1.dbo.Orders
                     ADD CONSTRAINT PK_OrdersOrderID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderID);'
EXEC Live1.sys.sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

Which works with no errors :)

Comment: You can add default value.. I assume that may solve it

Comment: What happens if you have both these statements in a SSMS window and try to run them both at once? Does the same error occur? Possibly, the SQL Server parser is trying to validate both statements - and the second of course will fail the check before the first one has completed. So try to run these two statements in **separate** agent job steps - first just alter the column to NOT NULL; and then in a second step add the PK constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because at the time of parsing the statements, when SQL Server parses the second statement the column is still nullable.

Two options:

- Run the second statement as a dynamic SQL query using `sp_executesql`. This will create a separate context and when that query is parsed, the first one will already have run.
- Create a stored procedure for just adding the primary key. Execute that one in place of the direct alter/add constraint statement.

PS: A semicolon serves to separate (or terminate if you will) statements on a language level. It has no run-time functionality.

Comment: "*A semicolon only serves to separate statements. It has no functionality per se."* It most certainly has a function; to terminate statements. Some statements require the  **previous** one to be terminated correctly, and it's deprecated that you do not terminate them properly.

Comment: It has no run-time functionality, I thought that would be self-evident seeing as most languages have some sort of separator and none have run-time functionality. The post scriptum is there to respond to the OP's rather weird claim that it is meant to "wait" or something.

Comment: That isn't what you appear to be saying in your answer though. It reads as if you suggest it's not needed; that isn't the case.

Comment: Better the way it is written now?

Comment: Forgive my weirdness, the way this error message is presented isn't like the usual Syntax Error you get at parse level, this reads like an execution level error. Also, my stored procedure parses just fine when I run an ALTER PROCEDURE on it, so you can forgive my ignorance in thinking that I'd already passed the parse police! One to bear in mind for the future I think!

Comment: @GeoffGriswald A stored procedure isn't pre-compiled (though individual statements can be), that way temporary tables can be used in statements without defining those temporary tables in the same scope (i.e. within the stored procedure). That can be confusing sometimes, but is a necessary evil. Also, consider stored procedures without schema binding, referencing tables that afterwards are changed. Also, I was not accusing you of weirdness ;-) it was the statement itself.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald Perhaps [this part in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#general-remarks) will explain a bit better than I can: `When a procedure is executed for the first time, it is compiled to determine an optimal access plan to retrieve the data. Subsequent executions of the procedure may reuse the plan already generated if it still remains in the plan cache of the Database Engine.` etcetera.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald And [a bit further](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#limitations-and-restrictions): `A procedure can reference tables that do not yet exist. At creation time, only syntax checking is performed. The procedure is not compiled until it is executed for the first time. Only during compilation are all objects referenced in the procedure resolved.`